# Is there a way to hide a view when there is not enough room for it

Tags: android, xml, layout, space

Let's imagine I put 10 `ImageView`s into a `LinearLayout`. On some phones, the screen is too small, only 9 could fit. The 10th will be smaller.

Is there a way to hide the 10th if there is not not enough room on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can get the Height of your screen, and then add an image and calculate the height sum of all the images you added, and compare, if (sumHeightImages >= screenHeight) : then  set the visibility of the rest images to GONE :)

Comment: It's for a widget I only have RemoteViews, so I wonder if there is a trick for doing this.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `ScrollLayout` with the nested `LinearLayout` that contains the `ImageView`s.